# How can I skip if number===0?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

When converting numbers to roman numerals, I need if the first number "2000" is larger than what is on the array provided, add the maximum value of the array until it comes to 2000.

I run into a problem after it is done putting out the numerals for 2000. It goes to the next number in the array, which is ZERO! [2000,0,80,4]

I need to skip if it is zero. I attempted a finalnum[i]!=0.

```js
for (i = 0; i < finalnum.length; i++) {

  var idx = romanNum.indexOf(finalnum[i]);

  if (idx === -1 && finalnum[i] != 0) {
    var max = romanNum.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return (Math.max(a, b));
    });
    var amountoftimes = finalnum[i] / max;
    idx = romanNum.indexOf(max);
    romans.push(romanEquiv[idx].repeat(amountoftimes));
  } //end of if statement


}

}
```

```js
var romanNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];
var romanEquiv = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX', 'XC', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'CD', 'D', 'DC', 'DCC', 'DCCC', 'CM', 'M'];



function convertToRoman(num) {

  //convert num to separate numbers
  var indices = [];
  var romans = [];

  //split out the number first
  var nextint = num.toString().split("");
  var nextarr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nextint.length; i++) {
    var firstnum = "0".repeat(nextint.length - i - 1);
    nextarr.push(nextint[i] + firstnum);
    var finalnum = nextarr.map(Number);
  }

  //find the romannumerals
  for (i = 0; i < finalnum.length; i++) {

    var idx = romanNum.indexOf(finalnum[i]);

    if (idx === -1 && finalnum[i] != 0) {
      var max = romanNum.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return (Math.max(a, b));
      });
      var amountoftimes = finalnum[i] / max;
      idx = romanNum.indexOf(max);
      romans.push(romanEquiv[idx].repeat(amountoftimes));
    } //end of if statement
  }

  return romans.join('');
}

console.log(convertToRoman(2084));
```

Comment: `convertToRoman()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @barmar sorry i forgot to put the console.log statement, fixed now.

Comment: It would be significantly clearer to make that a `return` statement, and then call `console.log(convertToRoman(2084))`.

Answer (score 0):

Test if `finalnum[i] == 0`, and skip to the next number with `continue;`.

However, the rest of your code doesn't seem to work correctly. It still just returns `"MM"`. There are other problems in your algorithm that

You should also use `return` in the function. Do the `console.log()` in the caller.

BTW, the `reduce` loop can be replaced with:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, romanNum);
```

I'm not really sure why you need this variable, and you certainly don't need to calculate it each time through the loop, since the `romanNum` array never changes. It seems to be part of your confused algorithm. There are lots of other questions on SO (and also [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)) about converting to Roman numerals, you can look at them.

```js
var romanNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];
var romanEquiv = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX', 'XC', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'CD', 'D', 'DC', 'DCC', 'DCCC', 'CM', 'M'];

function convertToRoman(num) {

  //convert num to separate numbers
  var indices = [];
  var romans = [];

  //split out the number first
  var nextint = num.toString().split("");
  var nextarr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nextint.length; i++) {
    var firstnum = "0".repeat(nextint.length - i - 1);
    nextarr.push(nextint[i] + firstnum);
    var finalnum = nextarr.map(Number);
  }

  //find the romannumerals
  for (i = 0; i < finalnum.length; i++) {
    if (finalnum[i] == 0) { // skip zeroes
      continue;
    }
    var idx = romanNum.indexOf(finalnum[i]);

    if (idx === -1 && finalnum[i] != 0) {
      var max = romanNum.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return (Math.max(a, b));
      });
      var amountoftimes = finalnum[i] / max;
      idx = romanNum.indexOf(max);
      romans.push(romanEquiv[idx].repeat(amountoftimes));
    } //end of if statement
  }
  
  return romans.join('');
}

console.log(convertToRoman(2084));
```

Comment: thanks @Barmar I edited my original code, but the problem i am having now is the code skips over the "80". it is returning MMIV when it should return MMLXXXIV.  Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: I undid your edit, since my answer makes no sense when you merge it into the question.

Comment: BTW, please post properly indented code. You can use the Tidy button in the snippet editor to clean up the indentation.

Comment: fixed it now. Still can't figure out how to get the loop to run properly after it has determined to ignore zero

Comment: Your whole design seems very confusing. Why split the input into an array of characters, you should deal with it as a number. Find the maximum element of `romanNum` that's less than the input, calculate the number of repetitions, add them to the result and subtract from the input. Then repeat this until the input is 0.